# Handle X11 events with Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, x11, xcb

I am porting my application from Qt4 to Qt5.

As far as I know, Qt5 does not support handling Xlib events anymore and uses
XCB events (event handler gets `xcb_generic_event_t` object). However `spnav` library I am using supports only X11 events (it parses `XEvent` object to retrieve the necessary information). Is it possible to handle X11 events in Qt5  or convert `xcb_generic_event_t` to `XEvent`?

In Qt4 code looked like:

```
bool MyApplication::x11EventFilter(XEvent *event) 
{
    spnav_event sev;
    spnav_x11_event(event,&sev);

    if(sev.type == SPNAV_EVENT_MOTION) 
    {
           emit joystickPositionEvent(sev.motion.x,sev.motion.y,sev.motion.z,sev.motion.rx,sev.motion.ry,sev.motion.rz);
    } 
    else if(sev.type == SPNAV_EVENT_BUTTON)
    {   
        emit joystickButtonEvent(sev.button.bnum,sev.button.press!=0);
    }

    return false;   
}
```

Comment: Take a look at  [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractnativeeventfilter.html)

Comment: @AlexisP. I tried this, but the filter method has the following prototype. `bool QAbstractNativeEventFilter::nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result)`. `void* message` is actually pointer to `xcb_generic_event_t` and I cannot retrieve useful information from this type of object

Comment: You'll have to include "X11/Xlib.h" and manually synthesize an `XEvent` from `xcb_generic_event_t`.

Comment: @KubaOber I understand this. The question was if there is a common way to do it

Comment: That is the "common" way to do it, I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 1):

In case others encounter the same issue: spnav_x11_event() only requires a couple fields to be copied - here's the code I've ended up with for FreeCAD:

```
spnav_event navEvent;

// Qt4 used XEvents in native event filters, but Qt5 changed to XCB.  The
// SpaceNavigator API only works with XEvent, so we need to construct a
// temporary XEvent with just enough information for spnav_x11_event()
auto xcb_ev(static_cast<const xcb_client_message_event_t *>(message));
if ((xcb_ev->response_type & 0x7F) == XCB_CLIENT_MESSAGE) {
    XClientMessageEvent xev;

    xev.type = ClientMessage;
    xev.message_type = xcb_ev->type;
    memcpy(xev.data.b, xcb_ev->data.data8, sizeof(xev.data.b));
    xev.serial = 0; // These are just to squash warnings...
    xev.send_event = 0;
    xev.display = 0;
    xev.window = 0;
    xev.format = 0;

    if (!spnav_x11_event(reinterpret_cast<XEvent *>(&xev), &navEvent)) {
        return false;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
// navEvent is now initialised
```